Is it problematic to use percentages to describe a sample with less than 100 people?
This is a very basic, dumb question, but I couldn't find an answer, and on the top of that I'm generally suspicious of common sense/intuition.
I feel like it is "cheating" when saying "80% of people in the sample liked the banana flavor" when there are less than 100 people in the whole sample. But maybe I'm wrong, hence my question. I see at least two problems:

it could be somehow misleading if I omit to mention the sample size

there are percentages impossible to attain, for instance it's impossible to have any percentage between 0 and 10% if there are just 10 people in the sample


Am I overcautious here, and is it actually OK to use percentages like that? Or is it really a problem? Does it have other problems I did not identify?
Someone commented that it depends on the context, but I don't have a specific example in mind so my question is "it depends on what?". When is it fine to report percentages with a sample size less than 100, and when is it not fine?
TL;DR: If I understand correctly the current answers, it is always fine to report percentages as long as I report the sample size too. Not reporting the sample size along percentages is always problematic. Is that statement correct, or are there additional things to consider? Thank you.

I see a vote to close, but in my opinion this is a good question and I would like to see a good answer. I think you are right. While not "cheating" I would say it is misleading to report more precision than your data can provide. Instead of percent you could use "out of ten" phrasing. For example: 25 out of 30 people (or 8 out of 10) liked bananas.. In general, for computation never round, let the computer handle the numbers. But for reporting I think it's ok to follow common sense that you can justify.

@dariober it is a bit subjective. Indeed when you have 8 out of 10, then saying it is 80 out of 100 is wrong (80 per 100 is what 80 percent means, it is French). On the other hand percentages are often used as a general way to describe a fraction independent of the precision. Also mathematically 4/5, 0.8, and 80% are the same.

@SextusEmpiricus percentages are often used as a general way to describe a fraction independent of the precision: is that right? In my perception "83%" from, say, 25/30 suggests a precision that you don't have. Even if you round to "80%" you are still suggesting that it is "80" but not 81 or 79. I agree it is subjective and down to perception, but since people need to report results in layman terms, I think it is a good question.

@dariober in a way you can argue that you have that precision. It depends on whether you speak about the sample or the estimate about the population from which the sample is taken. In the first case you don't need a hundred to speak precisely about percentages. If 8 out of 10 in a sample like bananas then you know very precisely that it is $0.8$ and not $0.81$. For estimates about populations percentage are often very misleading no matter the sample size. Nobody expresses $8 \cdot 10^1 %$ in order to indicate the last significant digit. Eg. election polls saying 49% have more than ±1% error.

For sure this depends on the situation (how the information that you give will be used) and the audience.

A linked question is how to infer sample size from a mere percent breakdown. We are all too familiar with advertisements reporting customer evaluations but being coy about sample size. A easy warm-up is the report tha 33% said yes, 33% said no and the other person refused to answer. More interesting is trying to work out the smallest sample size consistent with a reported breakdown. A recent overview of the question with what references I know is in Speaking Stata: Finding the denominator: Minimum sample size from percentages https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X231212453

I don't undertand "This question does not appear to be about statistics ". Where should I ask it?

Nick Cox: I didn't even know it was possible to do that, thanks for the reference.

Christian Henning: my question is really general, I don't have a specific situation in mind.

@Donphag "my question is really general, I don't have a specific situation in mind." But then the answer is "it depends".

Christian Henning: Then my question is "it depends on what?" Or in other words, in what kind of situation it's fine, and in what kind of situation it isn't?

For questions about how to communicate something, always be conscious of your audience, what kind of background they have, and if you can possibly know how they may understand or misunderstand what you are saying. There are people who are inappropriately impressed by percentages (as you suspect). and there are people who are not... is it an academic audience? An audience with statistics background? These are important here. Good answer by @MarkWhite.

Related (duplicate?): https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/538859/minimum-total-n-value-for-denominator-when-calculating-a-percentage

Percentage is just a simple way to express a number
Percent, %, is just a number expressed as a fraction (or ratio) with the denominator being one hundred. It derives from Latin 'per hundred'. We also have permille, ‰, which means 'per thousand'. And you can go further with permyriad, per cent mille (also pcm), parts per million (ppm), or parts per billion (ppb).
All these numbers are used to make (dimensionless) numbers easier to express. With especially the large ones this is clear, ppm and ppb, can help to write small fractions or ratios like 0.00000123 much easier.
For percent it helps because people have a concept of it. We know what 8% tax means and it is easier than a 0.08 fraction tax.
Continuing with the tax example. A percentage doesn't need to indicate that the denominator in the case that it is applied to is equal to a hundred. We can speak about 8% of half a dollar, which is 4 cents.
In $9 \cdot 10^1\%$ of the cases with percentages, typically no significant digits are implied.
Also percents are often used without considering scientific notation and indicating the accuracy or imply that the last digit is an indication of the significance. 12.5% of a pizza means that it is 1 out of 8 slices, it can be way more inaccuracy than ±0.05%, A 33% often means one third. When a poll about elections results in 49%, but this figure has a ±5% error, then it is not reported as 5x10¹%. You never see such expressions.
For your sample the high accuracy, if you insist on interpreting it that way, is also technically not incorrect. Say, if your sample has 4 out of 5 people that like banana, then it is very accurately 0.8 which you can safely express as 80% without indicating that this number is too precise. The statistics about a sample can be very accurate (if you ignore errors in observing your sampled specimens, e.g. they might lie about bananas or you could have made a counting error).
A different issue
It are the estimates about the population that you infer from it which are inaccurate. For that reason, it is good to also report sample sizes. And if your sentence implies in it's context to refer to an estimate, then present a confidence interval, standard error or other way to express the accuracy.
This is a different issue than the usage of percentages to express numbers.
Alternative ways to write your sentence
Asside from the question is it good or not, you can wonder whether something else is better.
If your sample has size 10, then writing

8 of the 10 sampled people like banana flavor.

is easy to understand and more informative than

80% of the sampled people like banana flavor

However if your sample is size 321, then the following might not directly ring a bell with everyone

257 out of the 321 sampled people like banana flavor.

and computing it to 80% helps your readers to directly see what $\frac{257}{321}$ is.

Nitpick: "percent" is not derived from French, but from Latin per centum, "of a hundred". Modern French for "percent" is "pourcent". It may well be that older French may have been closer to "percent", but I would be quite surprised at any etymology that derived from French.

@StephanKolassa ah, it is 'pour cent' in French? Good nitpick. I assumed it was French because of the east/southern Arpitan and Occitan dialects which, I believe, use 'per cent'.

... which "dialects" (the distinction is to a degree subjective, but I would consider them full languages, as does Wikipedia) were successfully écrasés by the French centralizing state, but we digress...

Did you really intend to say "in 9% of cases", because that seems an oddly specific number when you are clearly making a generalisation. Did you mean 10^2 rather than 10^1? Or have I missed a joke here?

@user2390246 you got the joke, as you captured a mistake in it.

Between my friend and myself, we have a 500.000.000 ppb preference against pineapple pizza.

Let me add that there is also a cultural aspect to this issue. In my experience, Americans have an easier time with fractions and "x out of y", while everyone else in the world finds more natural to picture percentages in their mind. This is because the USA uses a measurement system where it is routine to work with units like "one third of an inch" and "3/4 cups of flour", and of course an inch is 1/12 of a foot to begin with. On the other hand, with the metric system it's more common to use decimals to express non-integer quantities.

@SextusEmpiricus, Might as well add the per myriad (per ten thousand) sign: ‱

@chux good point, I didn't know that sign (it's also not on my keyboard). I will add it if I have some more changes to make.

And 80% of percentages are made up on writing.

@fgrieu you mean $8 \cdot 10^1 %$ :)?

It depends on the situation and how you communicate it.
The short answer is: Yes, it is problematic, and you should not do this.
I am coming from an applied perspective; most of my career has been using techniques, ranging from simple to complex, but then explaining the results concisely and at the level of the audience's understanding. There are still times where stakeholders or clients will want to see percentages—even after I warn them that I'm suppressing numbers for a sample size that is too small. They insist they know the limitations and still want to see them. In this situation, I try to overstate that this is descriptive (only related to the given data I have) and not meant to be inferential (meant to draw conclusions about relationships generally).
Science is a social process, so communication is vital, and part of the skill of being a scientist is explaining these concepts in a way that is interpretable to your audience. Rhetorically, I find the idea that, "One person represents more than one percent" being problematic to be convincing to most audiences, albeit arbitrary.
Yes, it is problematic, but you will find yourself in situations you will have to do it, if you are working in applied science of any kind. The key there is communication.
Studying the communication numbers is just as important and fundamental to the practice of statistics as learning methodologies, software, etc. If you are interested in learning more about statistics and communication, I highly recommend Statistics As Principled Argument by Robert Abelson. Required reading for anyone whose job it is to communicate data to a wide variety of people, in my opinion.

The percentage (or proportion) is the maximum likelihood estimator for the true percentage (or proportion) for a binomial distribution*. That does not really change with the sample size. However, on its own it is not a sufficient statistic (i.e. only reporting the percentage throws away important additional information), while percentage (assuming no rounding) and total number are, similarly the number of positive cases and the total number, or the number of positive and negative cases, or percentage with confidence intervals etc. all are sufficient statistics.
To give an example 100% based on 1 trial tells you much less about the underlying parameter than 100% based on 100,000 trials. Not making it clear which it is is not good practice.
* Footnote on the binomial distribution bit: This of course assumes that there's no difference between all the trials that we know about (e.g. if we look at the proportion of deaths from any cause in a year across the population of a country, one would be silly to ignore additional information and think that this is an appropriate estimate for the proportion for all future years, even if e.g. the age distribution of the population changes, or medical treatment and/or sanitation options improve

Thanks, this is useful and informative. My question was originally about reporting; one of my worries was that reporting percentages (and nothing else) may give a misleading idea about the size of the sample. But given that not reporting sample size creates other statistical issues, as your answer mentions, I think this addresses my concern (i.e. we should always report the sample size along percentages).

@SextusEmpiricus even if it's not the sufficient statistics are enough to do anything else (assuming there's no important covariates etc.). E.g. if you want to do a fully Bayesian analysis, sufficient statistics also let you do that.

@Donphag It may also be useful to calculate a 95% confidence interval around the observed estimate. For example, with 10 individuals, an observed proportion of 80% suggests the true underlying proportion is between 44% and 96%. With 1000 individuals, observing a proportion of 80% means the true proportion is likely between 77% and 82%. Reporting the sample size is useful but somewhat indirectly, as it's really the effect on the precision of the experiment that's important.

Nuclear Joagie: very true. I think that what I had in the back of my mind (and that was not clear to myself before reading the answers) when I asked the question was how to deal with an audience that could be possibly mislead by percentages, if they are not accompanied with the sample size. I wonder how such audience would react to presenting them confidence intervals, and therefore what would be the best way to explain CIs to a lay audience, but perhaps that's a different question!

If you want to be really technical about it, I suppose you can consider the "percent" operator to be a correspondence (not a function) that maps the decimal value to all possible pairs of non-negative integers or perhaps real numbers giving that decimal value. Let $\%$ be the "percent" correspondence and $x$ be the value (e.g., $x = 10\% = 0.10$).
$$
\%(x) \in \left\{
\left(a,b\right)\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}\times \mathbb Z_{\ge 0} \mid \frac{a}{b} = x
\right\}
$$
In this formulation, there is no concern about how many observations there were: $80\%$ corresponds to both $80/100$ and $4/5$.
(Or we can just use the word the way people have used it for years while causing minimal problems in communication, despite the fact that almost no one has heard of the formal mathematical term correspondence.)

This is fine, but for everyone else percent % is just notation, so that 12.3% means just 12.3/100 and % is another way to write /100. Oddly, I don't know any statistical software which agrees. So, if I want to see 12.3 not 0.123 I have to multiply by 100 first, not change a display preference. I am told that MS Excel is supportive of such a view, but I don't use it unless I must.

Thanks, quite interesting and indeed I have never heard of correspondence before, so I have learned something today. What I take from your answer and Björn's is that it's fine to report percentages no matter the sample size, but I should take care of reporting the sample size too anyway.

@NickCox python agrees too. Try x=0.123; print(f'{x:%}')

@Stef Good for Python!
